# Convert a list of Strings to a list of Chars

Tags: list, scala

I'm trying to convert `List("123", "456")` to `List('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6')`. My current implementation is:

```
def convert(strings: List[String]): List[Char] = {
    val tmp = strings map (s => s.toList())
    tmp reduceLeft ((s1, s2) => s1 ::: s2)
}
```

It works but has to go through the same list twice (to parse each string into list, and to merge all list). Is there another way that I can go through the list only once? I think I need to use `reduce` but have no idea how to do it.

**Edit**: the reason I ask this question and want to use `reduce` is because it's related to the problem that I'm working on: given a method which gets an object of class A and returns some kind of list of objects of class B, find a way to covert a list of A to a list of B. So, I'm looking for an answer which is not specific to String or Char :)

Comment: For your real question/goal, you want `as.flatMap(_.getBs)`.  This is what `flatMap` is for.  (`as` is your list of object `A`, and `getBs` is the method that does the conversion (I'm assuming it's a method of `A` here; if not, just omit the `_.`.)

Answer (score 4):

How about: List("123", "456").flatten

```
scala> List("123", "456")
res0: List[java.lang.String] = List(123, 456)

scala> res0.flatten
res1: List[Char] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Here is a std. tail-recursive solution:

```
scala> res0.foldLeft(List.empty[Char])((accumulator, next) => accumulator ::: next.toList)
res2: List[Char] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```